# Unexpected value 'RotatingPlaneComponent' imported by the module

Tags: angular, spinner

I am trying to use **ng2-spin-kit-new**

while importing components getting 
**Unexpected value 'RotatingPlaneComponent' imported by the module**
don't know why I am getting this error at execution time.

**Extra Info:**

- I am working on JHipster generated angular2 project
- I am using webpack(not SystemJs.config.js)

I am following this URL:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-spin-kit-new

Comment: Try to move `RotatingPlaneComponent` from `imports` array to `declarations`

Comment: Yes, I added RotatingPlaneComponent in declarations array only. But no change in issue.